# How do I use the update function to change all variables in a field to 3 values. Replace didn't work, Update seems to get close? SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to change all entries to 3 values: Sales Ticket, Service Ticket and Technical Ticket. Replace seems to create new entries like Sales Ticket Ticket so I moved to the Update function which sounds like the correct one but I'm getting a syntax error on the below. Can you please assist?

'''
    UPDATE `tester-253410.test1.3foot`

SET string_field_1 = 'Sales Ticket'

WHERE string_field_1 = 'Plans and Deals (Sales Home Plans and Deals)'

AND string_field_1 = 'Home Telephone - Upgrade'

AND string_field_1 = 'Home Telephone - Plans & Deals'

AND string_field_1 = 'Handset Device - Plans & Deals'

AND string_field_1 = 'Business Cellphone - Plans & Deals'

AND string_field_1 = 'Plans and Deals (Sales Mobile)'

AND string_field_1 = 'Home Internet & Data - Plans & Deals'

AND string_field_1 = 'Handset Internet & Data - Upgrade'

AND string_field_1 = 'Handset Internet & Data - Plans & Deals'

AND string_field_1 = 'Buy Voice & Data Bundles'

AND string_field_1 = 'Buy Data Bundles (Express)'

AND string_field_1 = 'Business Internet & Data - Plans & Deals'

AND string_field_1 = 'Buy Airtime (Express)'

END,

SET string_field_1 = 'Service Ticket'

WHERE string_field_1 = 'Home Internet & Data - Cancellation'

AND 'Home Internet & Data - Billing Query' 
'''

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE tester-253410.test1.3foot
    SET string_field_1 = (CASE WHEN string_field_1 IN ('Plans and Deals (Sales Home Plans and Deals)', string_field_1 = 'Home Telephone - Upgrade', . . . )
                               THEN 'Sales Ticket'
                               WHEN string_field_1 IN ('Home Internet & Data - Cancellation', . . .)
                               THEN 'Service Ticket'
                               ELSE 'Technical Ticket'
                          END)
    WHERE true;
```

I simplified the long list of strings, so the `. . .` is for the additional string values.

Note:  I am not a fan of updating data in place.  I would instead suggest that you create a reference table with a lookup value for the ticket type.  Then you can simply join in the reference table to get the type -- and still have the original string.

Comment: I tried the above but it gives me the following error: UPDATE must have a WHERE clause at [1:1]. I tried to ad the WHERE clause at the end but that didn't work either.

Comment: @PieterleRoux . . . You just need `WHERE true`.